# How to change ctrl+space for visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, space, ctrl

By default <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> will show the intellisense, but I wish to change the shortcut, where should I change it?

Answer (score 3):

You can also go to **Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard** and check what is assigned to these shortcuts. The command name should be **Edit.CompleteWord.**

Answer (score 0):

Tools → Customize → Keyboard (under VS2012 at least).

Comment: Tools → Customize → Keyboard customize Toolbars and context menus but not shortcuts